# ObjC - NS_ENUM order?

Tags: objective-c, macros, enums

Given a NS_ENUM enumeration macro as such:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellStyle) {
    UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
};
```

What is the order of the elements? I mean the underlying integer values of each element.

For example, does UITableViewCellStyleDefault have value 0, UITableViewCellStyleValue1 have value 1, UITableViewCellStyleValue2 have value 2 and UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle have value 3?

Or can it be something like: UITableViewCellStyleDefault has value 30, UITableViewCellStyleValue1 has value 15, UITableViewCellStyleValue2 has value 23 and UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle has value 3?

Thanks

Comment: They are sequential starting with 0 when using NS_ENUM. NS_OPTIONS would be used to give arbitrary values. It's worth noting that with NS_ENUM the value shouldn't really matter. If your code is relying on some specific value that's probably code smell for some other issue.

Comment: ^ Thats the correct. You should make it into an answer

Comment: `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellStyle) {...};` is identical to `typedef enum : Integer {...} UITableViewCellStyle;` that is what `NS_ENUM` does.

Answer (score 0):

`NS_ENUM` values start with 0 and increase sequentially. So in the case of the `UITableViewCellStyle` example, as it is coded there those values would be correct. There's generally no guarantee that the order of the enumeration won't change, so you should really consider those values to be opaque; certainly you shouldn't be comparing them or trying to do anything clever with math in most cases. If the actual values matter `NS_OPTIONS` would be a better option, but even with that the underlying value could change and that shouldn't really have any impact on code that relies on the option set.